# Unable to run tensorflow multi-gpu with adam-optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am running Tensorflow locally with the following code:

```
    distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy(device='/cpu:0')
    config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(train_distribute=distribution)
    estimator_model_fn = create_model_fn()
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(estimator_model_fn, config=config)
    estimator.train(self.train_input_fn,steps=1000)
```

The model function uses `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` as the optimizer.
The call to train fails because of the following:

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
    packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 641, 
    in _apply_op_helper
    "(e.g.: a tf.Variable)") % (op_type_name, input_name))
    TypeError: 'ApplyAdam' Op requires that input 'm' be a mutable 
    tensor 
    (e.g.: a tf.Variable)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
```

If I change the optimizer to sgd the program runs without any problems.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you try [tf.contrib.optimizer_v2.AdamOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/optimizer_v2/AdamOptimizer)? I believe it has some improvements which make it more compatible with distribution strategies (and have yet to be merged backed into tf.train.AdamOptimizer).

Comment: Hi @AllenLavoie. Tried it but still get the same error. Do you think it's a bug in tensorflow? have anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Sounds likely. When you file a bug, boiling it down to a reproducible snippet (with a trivial model_fn and input_fn) would be super helpful. If you want another workaround to try, you could wrap your model_fn in a `with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), use_resource=True):` block to turn on resource variables, which sounds like it may fix things up.